# How to read local Google Maps data?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web

When I drag and zoom around Google maps, or use the 'browse' feature in Google [mapmaker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker), I assume that only basic map data like building polygon coordinates and transportation/restaurant/etc icon locations + on-hover data are being sent through the internet to my computer.  (This is in contrast to a more data-intensive scenario in which my mouse coordinates are constantly sent to servers through the internet, and those servers keep sending back new images accordingly.)

[1] Where are these map data stored?
[2] How can I access them?

---

**EDIT**
Per Lulyon's suggestion, I opened up Firefox's Firebug.  It appears that Google maps is coming in as images, not as dynamic/layered objects.  When you hover over a salient object, your browser sends a callback request like:
`GET https://mt3.google.com/mapslt/ft?lyrs=gw%3Adirect%3AGFwQAlABWgZsbXE6Kip1wBWuQHoFZjphbnk%7Cgid%3AXTlZKwxnPFg6qxnrb95r6g&x=84590&y=203485&z=19&hl=en&xc=1%2C17452890%2C3%2C7&callback=_xdc_._ihjf8sfqe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1] Map data is overlaid server-side, then sent to client as images.  E.g.:

```
GET https://mt3.google.com/mapslt?lyrs=gw:direct:GFwQAlABWgZsbXE6Kip1wBWuQHoFZjphbnk|gid:XTlZKwxnPFg6qxnrb95r6g&x=5283&y=12716&z=15&hl=en
```

`mt3` server
`mapslt` **???**
`lyrs=gw` **???**
`direct:...|gid:...` presumably specifies the ID of the image after it was overlaid with landmarks and red building polygons server-side.
`x=[0, 2^z - 1] y=[0, 2^z - 1]` specifies tile coordinate
`z=[0,21]` specifies zoom level (note that number of tiles is dependent on zoom level)
`hl:en` english language

[2] One must acquire calibrated images in which pixels can be mapped to lat/long.  This may be performed, e.g., by specifying xyz coordinates (`lyrs=m@[\d]+` **???**):

```
http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@129&hl=en&x=23&y=13&z=5
```

or using the [static maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).  Finally, one can process the images for the desired objects (e.g. via color thresholding) and then determine the lat/long of the pixels through [Mercator projection](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/).

---

**Please fill in ??? if you know.**

Answer (score 5):

press F12, check all the resources your browser displaying. You can find all the images link in the resource tab.

Comment: F12 doesn't seem to work on Firefox.  Instead, right click -> Inspect Element.